# For activities of type Email, how do I get the id for the activity just created during hook_civicrm_postProcess?

Tags: activities

Normally during hook_civicrm_postProcess, you can get the id of the just created activity from `$form->_activityId`. For activities of type Email, I can't see how to get the activity id. Am I just missing something simple?

I don't think I can use hook_civicrm_post instead because I want to use information in the form that isn't in the activity object, but the form info isn't available in hook_civicrm_post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of 5.36 this wouldn't be possible in a way consistent with other activity types anyway, because if there's multiple recipients the system will now create multiple activities, so in 5.36+ the form doesn't correspond to a single activity like with other activity types.